Connection string exacly the same to same Power BI dataset in both Test and Prod workspace in Excel
I have a problem where I have a Power BI semantic model in 2 different workspaces, one for Test and one for Prod.
A user is accessing the dataset via a PivotTable in Excel connecting with "From Power BI"
My idea is that the user can take a copy of his Excel file and then adjust the connection string to connect to the semantic model in the Test workspace for testing new functionality and regression testing.
However, when comparing the connection string between Prod and Test they are exactly the same, so I do not know how to distinguish between them.
Is there any other config, except the connection string, that hold info about what workspace is used?
I would expect some difference in the connection string so that is points to either of the workspaces.

You should find that the Initial Catalog=... property in the connection string has the dataset GUID, and this should differ for each dataset. There is an alternative, are your two workspaces on Premium-per-user or higher?

Hi  @SamNseir, thanks for your answer! Yes, we are using Premium-Per-User for the two workspaces, what impact does that have?

Repeating first answer in the comments:
You should find that the Initial Catalog=... property in the connection string has the dataset GUID, and this should differ for each dataset.
Alternative approach if using Premium-Per-User workspaces
With PPU and higher, you can connect to the dataset via XLMA and use this in Excel instead of From Power BI. Here are the steps...

In Power BI Service, go to your Workspace Settings, and under Licence info at the bottom, you'll find Connection link. Copy this address.

In Excel, in Data tab, goto Get Data > From Database > From Analysis Services


In the popup window, paste the Workspace connection link, in the Server name box. Set Log on credentials to Use the following User Name and Password, and leave these blank. Then hit Next >.

The authentication window popup should appear, then you can select your dataset. Then Finish.

Lastly select PivotTable Report.


You may prefer the above, as the end user can simply change the Workspace name in the Connection Properties.
